# Unable to fetch data from Room database using view model

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-viewmodel

I am using room db in my app and I am using MVVM design pattern.When I am creating view model in that at the time of accessing dao method its showing me below error.

```
No value passed for parameter 'context'
```

Below is my code:

**RoomDb.kt**

```
@Database(entities=[UserEntity::class],version = 1)
abstract class RoomDb: RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun useDao():UserDao

companion object{

    private var INSTANCE:RoomDb ?= null

    fun getRooomDb(context: Context): RoomDb{

        if(INSTANCE == null){

          INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder<RoomDb>(
              context.applicationContext,RoomDb::class.java,"AppDb"
          ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        }

        return INSTANCE!!
     }
   }
}
```

**UserDao**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAllUsers(): List<UserEntity>

@Insert
fun insertUser(user: UserEntity)

@Delete
fun deleteUser(user: UserEntity)

}
```

**HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel: ViewModel(){

fun allUser(){

    val db = RoomDb.getRooomDb().useDao()
  }
}
```

I am getting error in `RoomDb.getRooomDb().useDao()` line.Someone let me know how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed actually in `HomeViewModel` class I have to use `AndroidViewModel` and not `ViewModel` because I need to pass the context in viewmodel in this case `ViewModel` don't have any way to get a context but in `AndroidViewModel` we can pass context so `HomeViewModel.kt` should be like this:

**HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application){

fun allUser(): LiveData<List<UserEntity>> {

    val dao = RoomDb.getRooomDb(getApplication()).useDao()
 
  }
}
```